# Google pay “the transaction may be risky.For your safety ,it cant be completed at this time” what i do to remove this here is code

Tags: android

[I am showing this error on only google pay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdev7.jpg)3

i am using  this to get payment through google pay UPI it give error "the transaction may be risky.For your safety ,it cant be completed at this time" what i do to remove this here is code. Only google pay showing this error other UPI apps transaction is successfull.I have use google pay business UPI id.

I have use this two ways but showing same error,

1)

```
String GOOGLE_PAY_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user";
int GOOGLE_PAY_REQUEST_CODE = 123;

Uri uri =
    new Uri.Builder()
        .scheme("upi")
        .authority("pay")
        .appendQueryParameter("pa", "your-merchant-vpa@xxx")
        .appendQueryParameter("pn", "your-merchant-name")
        .appendQueryParameter("mc", "")
        .appendQueryParameter("tr", "1234")
        .appendQueryParameter("tn", "Test")
        .appendQueryParameter("am", "10.00")
        .appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
        .appendQueryParameter("url", "")
        .build();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(uri);
intent.setPackage(GOOGLE_PAY_PACKAGE_NAME);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, GOOGLE_PAY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

2. 

```
final int UPI_PAYMENT = 0;

  Uri uri =
        new Uri.Builder()
            .scheme("upi")
            .authority("pay")
            .appendQueryParameter("pa", "your-merchant-vpa@xxx")
            .appendQueryParameter("pn", "your-merchant-name")
            .appendQueryParameter("mc", "")
            .appendQueryParameter("tr", "1234")
            .appendQueryParameter("tn", "Test")
            .appendQueryParameter("am", "10.00")
            .appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
            .appendQueryParameter("url", "")
            .build();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(uri);

 Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(upiPayIntent, "Pay with");
 if(null != chooser.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())) {
            startActivityForResult(chooser, UPI_PAYMENT);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(PaymentDetailsActivity.this,"No UPI app found, please install one to continue",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: i have share my code.

Comment: I am also facing this problem

Comment: Any udpate on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a recent change in their system, many users are struggling with this issue.
There is an [open issue](https://github.com/googletez/inapp-payment-samples/issues/8) in git too

If I have to guess for it to work with Google Pay.
It needs the merchant code which you are passing as an empty string.

check this [link](https://support.google.com/pay/business/answer/7684271?hl=en) to see how to do that.

Use whichever method after registering it as Marchant just add **marchant-code**

```
new Uri.Builder()
        .scheme("upi")
        .authority("pay")
        .appendQueryParameter("pa", "your-merchant-vpa@xxx")
        .appendQueryParameter("pn", "your-merchant-name")
        .appendQueryParameter("mc", "your-merchant-code")
        .appendQueryParameter("tr", "1234")
        .appendQueryParameter("tn", "Test")
        .appendQueryParameter("am", "10.00")
        .appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
        .appendQueryParameter("url", "")
        .build();
```

And you shouldn't see an error.

Also if already registered, [how to find Merchant ID](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7163092?hl=en) ?

Comment: Thank you sir. But i have also use my google pay business Merchant ID  of mobile app. but my business profile is incomplete on checking on PC. So what merchant id i want use. mobile app business account merchant id or completed  business profile merchant id which is show on PC.

Comment: check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7IJd0toWog this will help you in creating business a/c. Disclaimer: Video is in hindi

Comment: I am also facing this issue can anyone help me for this issue

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with a transaction reference(tr) number under 30 characters and also make sure mc value is correct.

```
Uri uri =
new Uri.Builder()
.scheme("upi")
.authority("pay")
.appendQueryParameter("pa", "your-merchant-vpa@xxx")
.appendQueryParameter("pn", "your-merchant-name")
.appendQueryParameter("mc", "")
.appendQueryParameter("tr", "xyzshdfhsd") // less than 30 characters
.appendQueryParameter("tn", "Test")
.appendQueryParameter("am", "10.00")
.appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
.build();
```

I hope it would resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Normally if u use saving account for business purposes you may get this error as "Risky". So for using business purposes use gpay business. Your problem may get solved.

Comment: Even on the business account im getting this error. What could be the reason?